Add fields in Wazuh FIM Alerts
I'm currently working on a project involving the SIEM Wazuh and I'm wondering if it's possible to add new fields to the FIM alerts.
The idea is to add an attribute "sha256_creation" to always get the hash at the creation of the file.
Is there a way to achieve this ?
I'm still new to Wazuh, thank you in advance for all your answers and advice.
I searched in the documentation but couldn't find any clear way to do what I want.
